where separable and reflexive being used
I am confused where is the assumption that the space is separable and reflexive is being used here in following Lemma.
This is lemma 4.2.2 from book Calculus of Variations by Jost and Li-jost
Theorem 2.2.4 is Mazur's theorem which is as following:
Mazur's theorem - Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space and let $\left\{x_j\right\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X$ be a sequence converges weakly to some $x \in X$.
Then there exists a sequence $\left\{y_k\right\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X$ made up of finite convex combination of the $x_j$ 's of the form
$$
y_k=\sum_{j \leq k} \lambda_j^{(k)} x_j
$$
such that $y_k \rightarrow x$ strongly that is $\left\|y_k-x\right\| \rightarrow 0$.
Lemma: Let $V$ be a convex subset of a separable reflexive Banach space, $F: V \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ convex and lower semicontinuous. Then $F$ is also lower semicontinuous w.r.t. weak convergence.
Proof. Let $\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset V$ converge weakly to $x \in V$. We may assume that $F\left(x_n\right)$ converges to some $\kappa \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}$. By Theorem 2.2.4, for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and every $\varepsilon>0$, we may find a convex combination
$$
y_m:=\sum_{n=m}^N \lambda_n x_n \quad\left(\lambda_n>0, \sum_{n=m}^N \lambda_n=1\right)
$$
with
$$
\left\|y_m-x\right\| \leq \varepsilon
$$
Since $F$ is convex,
$$
F\left(y_m\right) \leq \sum_{n=m}^N \lambda_n F\left(x_n\right)
$$
Given $\varepsilon>0$, we choose $m=m(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ so large that for all $n \geq m$,
$$
F\left(x_n\right)<\kappa+\varepsilon
$$
Letting $\varepsilon$ tend to 0 , we get from (4.2.1)
$$
\limsup _{m \rightarrow \infty} F\left(y_m\right) \leq \kappa
$$
Since $F$ is lower semicontinuous
$$
F(x) \leq \liminf _{m \rightarrow \infty} F\left(y_m\right) \leq \limsup _{m \rightarrow \infty} F\left(y_m\right) \leq \kappa=\lim F\left(x_n\right)
$$
This shows weak lower semicontinuity of $F$.

I don't know for the reflexive part of the assumption, however the separable part is most likely used to have the equivalence between (weak) (lower) (semi)continuity and sequential (weak) (lower) (semi)continuity. That's only a guess from my end though.

It seems that the result is only about semicontinuity along a weakly converging sequence. In that case neither reflexivity nor separbility are used.

This is lemma 4.2.2 from book Calculus of Variations by Jost and Li-jost and whenever they have to use this theorem they say space is atfirst reflexive and separable like in Theorem 4.3.1, so I am confused

Looking at the book itself, or at least the section this is extracted from, it does seem like the authors just wanted to be safe topology-wise, as they wanted to have sequential characterisations for their notions.
